# How to use std::transform with a lambda function that takes additional parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, lambda

In C++ 11 (or higher) can I use `std::transform` and a lambda function to transform a vector that also takes other parameters?  For example, how do I pass `param` to the lambda function below?

```
std::vector<double> a{ 10.0, 11.0, 12.0 };
std::vector<double> b{ 20.0, 30.0, 40.0 };
std::vector<double> c;
double param = 1.5;
//The desired function is c = (a-b)/param   
transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), std::back_inserter(c),
          [](double x1, double x2) {return(x1 - x2)/param; });
```

`std::transform` wants a function with two input parameters. Do I need to use `std::bind`?

Comment: There is no need to use `std::bind` ever. Lambdas can do everything `bind` can and more. It really ought to be deprecated and eventually removed.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I think there is at least one edge case that `bind` can and lambdas cant, dont remember what it was and never encountered it myself so I just stick to "Lambdas can do everything" ;)

Comment: @user463035818 There is an edge case detailed [here](http://www.sdowney.org/2017/06/why-stdbind-cant-be-formally-deprecated/)

Comment: @JesperJuhl: I'd also not deprecate `std::bind` as long as http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0573r0.html (abbreviated lambdas) isn't approved. Lambdas currently carry a lot of syntactic noise with them, and some people may consider `std::bind` easier to read for certain use cases.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you for that link. Learned something new today.

Comment: @Christian Hackl - Thank you for that link. That's really interresting reading. Teaching me a few things 

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to capture param in your capture list:

```
transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), std::back_inserter(c),
          [param](double x1, double x2) {return(x1 - x2)/param; });
```

Capturing it by reference also works - and would be correct if param was a big class. But for a double `param` is fine.

Answer (score 6):

This is what the [lambda capture](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#ClosureType::Captures) is for.  You need to specify `&` or `=` or `param` in the capture block (`[]`) of the lambda.

```
std::vector<double> a{ 10.0, 11.0, 12.0 };
std::vector<double> b{ 20.0, 30.0, 40.0 };
std::vector<double> c;
double param = 1.5;
//The desired function is c = (a-b)/param   
transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), std::back_inserter(c),
          [=](double x1, double x2) {return(x1 - x2)/param; });
//         ^ capture all external variables used in the lambda by value
```

In the above code we just capture by value since copying a double and having a reference is pretty much the same thing performance wise and we don't need reference semantics.